# Tinymce editor text alignment in noneditable contet

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I've created a custom tinymce plugin to Add Headers,

- (this plugin used to add readonly text into the editor)
- these headers are inserted into a div with attribute
  contenteditable="false"
- Like `<div class="headerDiv" contenteditable="false">Marks</div>`
  (headerDiv is used to set the div as inline)

I havn't use the tinymce noneditable plugin regex , for me it's not working on inserting from a listbox. (please check the images)
[image]

[image]

**The problem** arises when i try to align the selected content with noneditable headers,
the headers will displayed on next line. (please check the image)
[image]

I've checked the tinymce_src.js, from that i understand how alignment works,
they get the content from the editor and wrap a div around it,
and align that div using text-align property.
In wrapping section they check the selected content has a html tag,
if the tag was found then they split the content into 3 
i.e

- content before the tag
- content with html tag
- content after the tag

and wrap this 3 part with a div

Example for tinymce selected content : raw tepmlate Marks

- part 1 : `<div style="text-align:center">raw tepmlate</div>`
- part 2 : `<div style="text-align:center"><div class="headerDiv" contenteditable="false">Marks</div></div>`
- part 3 : `<div style="text-align:center"> </div>`

Any guidance and help is appreciated..!

Comment: hmm, what is your question?

Comment: I want to align the editor content with noneditable header, after alignment the content must be in same line

Answer (score 0):

```
style="display: inline-block;"
```

?